# MySQL Workbench 6.3 can't find performance_schema after moving Mysql

Tags: mysql, connection, workbench

I moved my MySQL files and directory to a different volume on the same server. After setting the ownership back to the mysql user, I started the service and everything seems fine.

The `options-file` is still at the default location `/etc/my.cnf`

I can connect to MySQL with `mysql -u` and I also see the users in `mysql.user` table.

If I try to connect with `MySQL Workbench 6.3`, I recive the following error:

[Mysql Workbench Error Message][[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0t0h.jpg)

Has anybody an idea How I can change the file location in MySQL Workbench, so that it's able to find the  `performance_schema`, or am I missing something?

Comment: Please Check the error log for errors or warnings and edit your post. Which tutorial did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I havent changed the ownership of the tables in the performance_schema databaase to mysql user. After I changed all tables ownership to mysql, I restarted the service and everything worked like a charm.

[Table Ownership](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaBMp.png)

Cheers
Chester

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_upgrade worked for me:

```
# mysql_upgrade -u root -p --force
# systemctl restart mysqld
```